# Hiding page title on GitHub pages but leaving it on tab

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I am working on a personal website hosted using GitHub pages and using the [Minimal Mistakes](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/) theme forked from the [academicpages](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io) GitHub repository.

Under the `_pages` directory we build pages on the website following the basic format:

```
---
permalink: /
title: "Page Title"
excerpt: "Page excerpt"
author_profile: true
redirect_from: 
  - /title/
  - /title.html
---
BODY OF PAGE
```

I would like to add a page title to one of my HTML pages (ie. personal.html) to show the title in the tab in the web browser when the page is visited.

However, I do not want the tile to display on the page however or leave any space for it.

A few places suggest something along the lines of using `{display: none}`.

Would this work or would this hide the title on both the tab area and the page title (header) area? Further, where would I put this to implement this?

**Edit:** Said another way - I want the page title to show up only on the web browser tab but not on the page itself.

Any advice, links to any resources, or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`academicpages.github.io/_layouts/single.html`](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/single.html) layout HTML file, you find some lines related to the page title / HTML h1 tag, for example:

```
{% if page.title %}<h1 class="page__title" itemprop="headline">{{ page.title | markdownify | remove: "<p>" | remove: "</p>" }}</h1>{% endif %}
```

When the page title is defined in a page, this part of the layout HTML is used and the title is displayed.

The page title gets a CSS class, in this case, `page__title`.

Modify the [CSS for the page__title class here](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/25c30de2b4ce3e3f23559384699bb4b9865d6473/_sass/_page.scss#L153) to see if this works (I could not test it but I will do if needed).

CSS with `display: none`:

```
.page__title {
  font-size: $type-size-2;
  display: none;

  @include breakpoint($small) {
    font-size: $type-size-1;
  }
}
```